# MySql - Selecting MAX & MIN and returning the corresponding rows

Tags: mysql

I trying to get the last 6 months of the min and max of prices in my table and display them as a group by months. My query is not returning the corresponding rows values, such as the date time for when the max price was or min..

I want to select the min & max prices and the date time they both occurred and the rest of the data for that row...
(the reason why i have concat for report_term, as i need to print this with the dataset when displaying results. e.g. February 2018 -> ...., January 2018 -> ...)

```
SELECT metal_price_id, CONCAT(MONTHNAME(metal_price_datetime), ' ', YEAR(metal_price_datetime)) AS report_term, max(metal_price) as highest_gold_price, metal_price_datetime FROM metal_prices_v2 
WHERE metal_id = 1
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180
GROUP BY report_term
ORDER BY  metal_price_datetime DESC
```

I have made an example, extract from my DB:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/617bcb2/4/0

My desired result would be to see the min and max prices grouped by month, date of min, date of max.. and all in the last 6 months.

thanks

UPDATE.
The below code works, but it returns back rows from beyond the 180 days specified. I have just checked, and it is because it joining by the price which may be duplicated a number of times during the years.... see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f501b/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  could use twice inner join on the subselect for min and max

```
select   a.metal_price_datetime
         , t1.highest_gold_price
         , t1.report_term
         , t2.lowest_gold_price
         ,t2.metal_price_datetime

  from metal_prices_v2 a
  inner join (
      SELECT  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(metal_price_datetime), ' ', YEAR(metal_price_datetime)) AS report_term
               , max(metal_price) as highest_gold_price

      from metal_prices_v2
      WHERE metal_id = 1
      AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180
      GROUP BY report_term
  ) t1 on t1.highest_gold_price = a.metal_price
  inner join (
     select   a.metal_price_datetime
         , t.lowest_gold_price
         , t.report_term

  from metal_prices_v2 a
  inner join (
      SELECT  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(metal_price_datetime), ' ', YEAR(metal_price_datetime)) AS report_term
               , min(metal_price) as lowest_gold_price

      from metal_prices_v2
      WHERE metal_id = 1
      AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180
      GROUP BY report_term
  ) t on t.lowest_gold_price = a.metal_price

 ) t2 on t2.report_term = t1.report_term
```

Comment: you miss some `ON` conditions

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  ..thanks  join for second table added

Comment: Thanks!. However, it only return one row..  How do i return the min and max with corresponding rows for the last 6 months?

Comment: Check if inner subquery retunrn  6 rows  or not .. and eventually updated  your question with a proper tabular sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge yes the inner query does return 5 rows..  How can i have to the whole query return the rows...

Comment: In your sqlfiddle return 2 rows  ..  check for data content http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/617bcb2/7

Comment: Yes.. sorry. but, where are the rest of the months.. e.g. Decembers min and max, and the last 6 months.... this is why i put 180 days.

Comment: Thanks... it pulls the data now... for some reason, when i run this query live, it pulls data from beyond 180 days..  do i have to put a where clause at the end?

Comment: actually, i can see why... it is matching the high or low price, but some prices are the same couple years back... so it is returning those rows instead of the one it found... (2013-09-27)

Comment: Then result for year and month are related  to the where condition you have  .. so if you need  a more refined  range for date  .. youn should build the proper where condition ..but this seems another question to  mee ..

Comment: thanks.. problem is, i cant ask another question, it limits to 1 for 1 day. lol! sorry.  i will try a where clause for each inner queries...

Comment: if you see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f501b/1     i have added 2012 rows... with the same price at 2018... and they are all being picked up....   as this query is matching all prices....  even if there are same price within the desired period..

Comment: A question per day seems strange to me  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask

Comment: oh ok.. but seems to me, i have the same problem regardless if i need to change the where clause to limit the range...  so regardless of the range, whether it is 2 months, 2 weeks, etc, it will still bring the wrong data if the price is the same...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f501b/3     ,, this should return  the correct value .. check for the t  on t.lowest_gold_price = a.metal_price and 
     DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180

Comment: Ok... yes, i was confused as it says February 2018 as Report Term for the last row which is dated 2012...

Comment: however  ..  SO in not a coding server  .. you have posted  a question and we have posted  (i think)  a valid  answer ..  is not fair  .. add  question to question  .. if you have some others question you should post a new properly described  question  .. and if my answer related to your original question is right you  should mark as accepted  .

Answer (score 0):

simplified version of what you should do so you can learn the working process.

You need calculate the min() max() of the periods you need. That is your first brick on this building.

you have tableA, you calculate min() lets call it `R1`

```
SELECT group_field, min() as min_value
FROM TableA
GROUP BY group_field
```

same for max() call it R2

```
SELECT group_field, max() as max_value
FROM TableA
GROUP BY group_field
```

Now you need to bring all the data from original fields so you join each result with your original table

We call those T1 and T2:

```
SELECT tableA.group_field, tableA.value, tableA.date
FROM tableA
JOIN ( ... .. ) as R1
  ON tableA.group_field = R1.group_field
 AND tableA.value = R1.min_value


SELECT tableA.group_field, tableA.value, tableA.date
FROM tableA
JOIN ( ... .. ) as R2
  ON tableA.group_field = R2.group_field
 AND tableA.value = R2.max_value
```

Now we join T1 and T2.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( .... ) as T1
JOIN ( .... ) as T2
  ON t1.group_field = t2.group_field
```

So the idea is if you can do a brick, you do the next one. Then you also can add filters like last 6  months or something else you need.

In this case the `group_field` is the `CONCAT()` value